# Issue using tensorflow.gather_nd when the length of the tensor containing the indices is greater than 32

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I am using tensorflow version 2.3.0 and keras. I am confused as to how the function tensorflow.gather_nd works. When I run this section of code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

SIZE = 32
INDEX = 2

def build_model():
    data_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(4,)
    index_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(2,)
    indices = tf.keras.backend.cast(index_input, dtype='int32')
    output = tf.gather_nd(data_input, indices)
    model = tf.keras.Model([data_input, index_input],
                           [output])
    return model

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = np.arange(4 * SIZE).reshape((SIZE, 4))
    indices = INDEX * np.ones((SIZE, 2))
    indices[:, 0] = np.arange(SIZE)

    test_model = build_model()
    indexed_data = test_model.predict([data, indices])
    print(indexed_data)
```

it runs properly and the output is correct.

```
[  2.   6.  10.  14.  18.  22.  26.  30.  34.  38.  42.  46.  50.  54.
  58.  62.  66.  70.  74.  78.  82.  86.  90.  94.  98. 102. 106. 110.
 114. 118. 122. 126.]
```

However, when I increase the batch size of the input data to a number greater than 32:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


SIZE = 33
INDEX = 2


def build_model():
    data_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(4,)
    index_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(2,)
    indices = tf.keras.backend.cast(index_input, dtype='int32')
    output = tf.gather_nd(data_input, indices)
    model = tf.keras.Model([data_input, index_input],
                           [output])
    return model


if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = np.arange(4 * SIZE).reshape((SIZE, 4))
    indices = INDEX * np.ones((SIZE, 2))
    indices[:, 0] = np.arange(SIZE)

    test_model = build_model()
    indexed_data = test_model.predict([data, indices])
    print(indexed_data)
```

I receive this error:

```
2020-09-05 13:46:40.165636: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1767] OP_REQUIRES failed at gather_nd_op.cc:47 : Invalid argument: indices[0] = [32, 2] does not index into param shape [1,4]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/Project/Gather_Test.py", line 25, in <module>
    indexed_data = test_model.predict([data, indices])
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 130, in _method_wrapper
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 1599, in predict
    tmp_batch_outputs = predict_function(iterator)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 780, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 814, in _call
    results = self._stateful_fn(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 2829, in __call__
    return graph_function._filtered_call(args, kwargs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 1848, in _filtered_call
    cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 1924, in _call_flat
    ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager))
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 550, in call
    ctx=ctx)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py", line 60, in quick_execute
    inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:  indices[0] = [32, 2] does not index into param shape [1,4]
     [[node functional_1/tf_op_layer_GatherNd/GatherNd (defined at /Users/user/PycharmProjects/Project/Gather_Test.py:25) ]] [Op:__inference_predict_function_105]

Function call stack:
predict_function
```

I have tried this using tensorflow versions 2.0.0, 2.1.0, and 2.2.0 as well and still get the same result. How can I make it index data with a batch size larger than 32?

Comment: Can you add a complete error traceback?

Comment: @AniketBote I have edited the post to include the entire error traceback.